# All posts are not shown well

Tags: bug, android-app

I'm using Nexus 5X. For some reason, all posts I'm trying to view are not shown well. I see blank page and I have to scroll a long way down to see the post. In addition, the comments and answers are not shown at all.

- App Version: 1.0.89
- Device Manufacturer: LGE
- Device Model: Nexus 5X

  - OS Version: 7.1.1 (3687331)